# Tomcat Realm is called after Valve

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbcrealm, tomcat-valve

i need your help. I developed a custom valve for tomcat which intercepts specific user requests for specific URIs (a kind of authorization), but it should only invoked after my JDBCRealm. I tried a lot so far to configure this behaviour in my server.xml but it does not work. My Valve is always invoked in front of the Realm.

The Realm is defined at Engine level and the Valve at Host level...i thought the tomcat chain would handle this order for me.

Can you please help me to get this running?